# The path between 2 vertices by using dfs

Tags: python, graph, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

I have a Python code like this:

```
def DFS(matrix, start, end):
    # TODO:

    path = []
    visited = {}

    stack = []  
   
    stack.append([start])
  
    visited.update({start: None})

    while stack:

        path = stack.pop()  
        node = path[-1] 

        if node == end:  
            break
        for i in range(len(matrix[node])):
            if matrix[node][i] > 0 and i not in visited:
                new_path = list(path)  
                new_path.append(i)  
                stack.append(new_path)  
                visited.update({i: node})
    print(path)
    return visited, path
```

The input is a adjacency matrix like this:
The first line is the start and end node.

```
1 6
0 0 9 3 0 0 9 0
0 0 8 5 5 7 6 7
6 9 0 4 2 5 6 8
5 1 2 0 2 4 7 9
0 3 6 8 0 6 6 5
0 6 3 9 9 0 4 0
5 1 8 1 5 3 0 5
0 3 9 8 3 0 7 0
```

My path is [1,6], Is that correct with DFS algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

My result is [1,2,3,4,5,6]. I reassign the start node with the last node which have visited. So the path will contain many other nodes.

```
 if(matrix[start][i] != 0 and i not in visited):
            visited.update({i:start})
            path.append(start)
            start = i
            break
```